# Issue in Roku 4 ultra

Tags: roku, brightscript

We have developed a new tv app and when we install it on roku 4 ultra  channel come on small screen not in full screen and the screen is a blank Colour purple with no vision. We only hear voices on the channel but when we test on roku 3 it's on full screen  and video also playing perfectly  since we don't have roku 4 ultra to test on that box also so can you guys explain what is the reason behind this issue?

Comment: you may need to test it on that device yourself to debug the issue. did you try to contact partner support at roku?

Comment: yes and they said there is nothng like that that affcets

Comment: did you compare your channel to a sample channel?  assuming the problem doesn't happen with the sample changes, make changes to the sample that are in your channel to see what affects it.

Comment: we have used fixed width and height for rectangle and video node may be it was the reason could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Check in the manifest that you don't have something like

```
ui_resolutions=hd,fhd
```

Sounds as if you have developer for HD (720p) resolution - that is fine, just tell it `ui_resolutions=hd`, so player will auto-scale on 1080p.

Not sure what's causing the other issue, "only audio" - but i bet it is the video playing *behind* that purple facade. Video always plays behind all graphics, so transparency hole or hiding the splash may be neded